# Neighbour has extended over the boundary of a potential house I was looking to buy

Tags: property, england-and-wales

So having initially looked at a house I found that everything was in good order and the seller seem genuine in respect everything being able to answer my question and to provide the relevant documents if requested.

Having gone back home and reviewed the listing, I noticed that the neighbours extended wall comes past the boundary and covers the potential house's side entrance (back end leading to the garden). So essentially...when you look at the side entrance from the front of the house, it doesn't reach the back entrance of the garden... You just see the neighbours brick wall... So the side entrance only to leads to a side door only (which the seller has currently blocked - 'as they don't use the side entrance').

I've been told that boundary lines stated on the land registry website (UK) doesn't specially specify boundaries but I fully suspect that either the neighbour has built on the other side after making a payment or they've just built it and risked it... Current sellers have been in the property for 12 years.

Any advice please?

Comment: We can't provide legal advice: that's what you have to pay a solicitor for. Can you edit to ask a specific question about the law?

Comment: Book land surveyors. They'll find out exactly where the boundaries are.

Answer (score 1):

Since the house isn't yours, you have no standing to do anything about it.

Let's say you decide for yourself that the house is worth X to you with the boundaries as they are physically, and worth Y (higher) to you with the boundaries on the land registry website.

If the seller is willing to sell for X, that's it. Buy it. If the seller wants more, feel free to tell them about the land registry website and tell them that you would pay more with the extra land. They might be able to do something, but that's not your problem.

What you shouldn't do is pay more than X and hope that you can take the neighbour to court and get more land. Even if you win the case in court, you will now have a neighbour who hates you, which is never good.

Comment: Or send a joint offer to both parties saying that you're willing to pay X to the property owner and Y-X to the neighbor to have all of the property listed on the registry.